# Could not find io.fabric.tools:gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics-android

I'm following official instructions of fabric

https://www.fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

This is my gradle.build file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
dependencies {
...
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.3'

    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

}

android {

compileSdkVersion 22

buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    ....
}

}
dependencies {
......
   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but when I try to sync my project, it says that could not find **io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.3** searched in following locations:

```
Error:Could not find io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.3.
Searched in the following locations:

    file:/home/dev-00/soft/android-studio-3.0.0/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.24.3/gradle-1.24.3.pom
    file:/home/dev-00/soft/android-studio-3.0.0/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.24.3/gradle-1.24.3.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.24.3/gradle-1.24.3.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.24.3/gradle-1.24.3.jar
 ...    Required by:
    project :
```

Comment: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In your `buildscript` block you have to add also the fabric repo.

```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
         //... jcenter(), google()...
         maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      }
   }

  dependencies {
     //......
  }
}
```

Comment: o right :/ now error is gone, but I can't use any instance of Fabric or Crashlytic  for example:  Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); says cannot resolve symbol Fabric

Comment: Try to clean, but this is some separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question

Comment: note that I had to move this to the top level `buildscripts.repositories` object block in the file. It did not work when the maven url entry was made under the `allprojects.buildscripts.repositories` object block of the file my allprojects

Comment: `Tope`s comment in correct. You should add the repo in `buildscripts.repositories`.